# Can't create connection pool and datasource in Glassfish for h2 database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, h2

Here's my glassfish-resources.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-connection-pool res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
datasource-classname="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
pool-resize-quantity="1" max-pool-size="5" steady-pool-size="0"
statement-timeout-in-seconds="60" name="jdbc/test_pool">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:h2:D:\test\test;IFEXISTS=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="root"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
  <jdbc-resource object-type="system-all" enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/test" pool-name="jdbc/test_pool" />
</resources>
```

After deploying war to server with **maven glassfish plugin** through m2eclipse, when i do `asadmin> list-jdbc-connection-pools` my connection pool is not in the list. I'm really lost

**EDIT.**

```
asadmin add-resources
```

works fine for some reason

Glassfish  3.1.2 (build 23)

POM.xml:

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <type>maven-plugin</type>
            </dependency>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <glassfishDirectory>d:\glassfish3</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>admin</user>
                    <passwordFile>d:\password.txt</passwordFile>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                    <domain>
                        <name>domain1</name>
                        <adminPort>4848</adminPort> <!-- mandatory for mvn glassfish:deploy -->
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**EDIT2**
Problem solved. Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Do you see the connection pool through the admin console?

Comment: You mean GUI? No, there's only TimerPool and DerbyPool

Comment: Are you using right maven plugin version as your GF server? The XML descriptor names/prologs changed from sun* to glassfish* recently.

Comment: added pom.xml please check it out.

Comment: Are you trying to leverage the Application Scoped Resources feature? https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/application_scoped_resources_in_glassfish

Comment: I don't understand :(( Do i need to remove "jdbc/" part from resources name? I have `glassfish-web.xml`, and `web.xml` also in `WEB-inf`.

Comment: Wow you are from glassfish team! Please help me out. I'm doing this whole thing because i wanted to set up security realm for my web-app. So idea was to create resources on deployment with glassfish-resources.xml and then manually create security realm in admin console gui. So jndi name for resource for security realm - `java:app/jdbc/test` or just `jdbc/test`?

Comment: What is the content of the war file that you are deploying... specifically the WEB-INF and META-INF directories... even more specifically, "Do you have a file named 'glassfish-resources.xml' with the content that you have described in this SOQ?"  Are you using "asadmin list-applications --resources --subcomponents" to see the resources?  They will not be visible in the output of the "asadmin list-jdbc-connection-pools" command.

Comment: Hey... just saw that you have gotten it working... That is great... Please be kind and share what you learned as an answer to this question so others will be able to resolve similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and add the connection pool directly from the **admin console**. then **ping** to see if its listening.

Comment: so now you can see your connection pool in the admin console?

Comment: Still cant add connection-pool by deploying war to server :(

Comment: you can view the admin console if glassfish server is running from a browser. it has good interface to see the resources and their connection pools. i use netbeans and i access it through: **http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf** i have no idea of maven

Comment: Even if i deploy war in admin console, connection-pool is still not created